# Emoji picker tool?

Tags: emoji

Is there any tool that helps choose Emoji to paste into the current document or program? Similar to the Emoji picking keyboard that appears in Android or iOS.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is very old, but I've also been interested in this matter for a while, so I've developed a [simple emoji picker tool for Ubuntu](https://github.com/gentakojima/emojione-picker-ubuntu).

The main issue with this approach is that you need to paste the emoji where you want it after choosing it.

Comment: pretty nice!  I do really wish it would work like a virtual keyboard and there was no need for pasting it !! nice job anyway

Comment: Thanks! I'm working on it, so keep tuned for future updates! :)

Comment: With the release of **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** you can use **emoji** on Ubuntu right **out of the box** 
more details here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1045916/1017209

Answer (score -2):

You can go here for a good emoji picker: http://emojikeyboard.org

Answer (score -2):

You can use pro emoji keyboard (or emojiselector) at http://emojiselector.com. They issued extension for Chrome, Opera, Firefox. This emoji keyboard is very cool with real feeling when typing.

Answer (score -5):

```
$ uname -a
Linux aardvark 3.13.0-61-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:21:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ apt-cache search emoji
fcitx-table-emoji - Flexible Input Method Framework - Emoji table
ibus-table-emoji - ibus-table input method: Emoji
librime-data-emoji - RIME schema data - Emoji
libunicode-japanese-perl - module for converting Japanese encodings
```

Yes.

Comment: Classic stackoverflow answer! 