# How to insert an emoji into a text in Ubuntu 18.04 and later?

Tags: 18.04, emoji

What are the possibilities to insert, choose and use an emoji in Ubuntu 18.04 and later?

Comment: in case Google has led someone here since their emojis have gone black and white here's a quick fix: `sudo curl -o /etc/fonts/local.conf https://pastebin.com/raw/atfUQQ2j`

Answer (score 144, accepted):

1. **Activities**: Clicking the Activities button in the top left corner in the GNOME desktop environment. Or press the Super key (Windows key) to get the same.
   GNOME has an application called **gnome-characters**. This provides you with several emojis and related characters. If you don't have this application, you can install it using: `sudo apt install gnome-characters`
   Once installed, this application has its own search provider.
   Make sure it is turn on: System settings > search tab > Characters
   You can search for any character name. You can see various suggestions as you type.
   [image]
   Once you find a character, press Enter so that the selected character will be copied to your clipboard. You can paste it using CTRL+V. [Source: [7 Tips to Get More Out of GNOME Search in Linux](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-search/)]
2. **Emoji Picker:** With the release of **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** you can use **emoji** on Ubuntu right **out of the box** , so you already have everything you need for the **native GTK Linux apps** like Gedit, Corebird, Rhythmbox and probably Geary ([Source: OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/use-emoji-linux-ubuntu-apps)). All you have to do to access the **emoji picker** in a native Linux app is **right-click** (or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> ) in a text-field and select the “**Insert Emoji**” option from the context menu. [image]
   This **picker pop-over** lets you:

   - Browse emoji by category
   - Pick from recently used emoji
   - Search for emoji by name
   - Click on an emoji to enter it
     The emoji picker even works on other Linux distros & desktops besides Ubuntu, including Ubuntu MATE and Ubuntu Budgie.
     Sadly the emoji picker doesn’t work everywhere . You won’t see the option provided in non-GTK apps, like Firefox, [Wire Messenger](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964757/how-to-install-the-wire-messenger-desktop-app-client-on-ubuntu), Chromium, or LibreOffice.
     If the app you’re using **doesn’t have that option**, please **file a bug**, like the one for [gedit](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790029).
     To change the keyboard shortcut, use the dconf-editor and navigate to `/desktop/ibus/panel/emoji/hotkey`.
     For more background info browse to [Ubuntu Community Hub](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/try-color-emoji-in-18-04/1492).
3. **Emoji Choice popup** (Ubuntu 18.10+): Handy tool, see [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1142721/30631) of [kenorb](https://askubuntu.com/users/78223/kenorb), please vote his answer up, too.
   Hitting <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>, then press <kbd>Space</kbd> works in most apps. You should see the Emoji Choice popup where you can select your unicode character.
4. [GNOME Shell Extension **Emoji Copy**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6242/emoji-copy/) for **non-GTK apps** like Firefox, [Wire Messenger](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964757/how-to-install-the-wire-messenger-desktop-app-client-on-ubuntu), Chromium, or LibreOffice:
   [image]
   It is a **fork** of [GNOME Shell Extension **Emoji Selector**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1162/emoji-selector/) which works up to GNOME 43. Thank you, [Didier L](https://askubuntu.com/users/38631/didier-l), for the tip!
5. **GNOME Characters app**: Another option to install to easily browse emoji.
   Optionally, you can enable emoji search in the Activities Overview by using the Settings app. Just open Settings > Search and turn on Characters.[image]
6. [**Emoji keyboard**](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/emoji-keyboard-app-linux): If you are **not on Gnome**, this is simple but effective. You can find more information on the **virtual keyboard-like emoji picker app** (plus an installer) over [on the project Github page](https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/emoji-keyboard).
   [image]
7. **UniEmoji** (for a specific input framework called IBus): "If you prefer to type them out for easy use, then there’s a very easy solution on Linux. It combines software to let you type in foreign languages, with an input method that gives it the ability to type in emojis. When everything is set up, you should be able to type whatever emoji you like, either by inputting them, or searching. This can be much faster and easier than something like a popup window, but takes a little more setting up." [For how to set this up, please check this article.](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/emoji-keyboard-linux/) As it is quite long, the integration of the instructions would push the boundaries of this answer.
8. [**Mojibar**](https://electronjs.org/apps/mojibar) could be an option (although not updated since 2017), it works on many desktop environments, see [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155795/30631) of [kissu](https://askubuntu.com/users/770066/kissu), please vote his answer up, too. [You can download the zip-folder of the Electron App](https://github.com/muan/mojibar/releases), and drag into your apps folder and it probably works without installing, just double-click on the `Mojibar` file.
9. **Emoji input to the on-screen keyboard** (Ubuntu 19.04+, [GNOME 3.32](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/03/best-gnome-3-32-features): it should make it easier to reply with a well-timed emote from a **touchscreen device**.
   [image]
10. [**Emote**](https://github.com/tom-james-watson/emote) was mentioned by [James, please vote the answer below up, too](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328351/30631). The emoji picker can be opened with either the keyboard shortcut (choosing one or several emojis) or by clicking the app icon again. More details [on the Github page](https://github.com/tom-james-watson/emote).
    Install the snap app from the Software Center or [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/emote) on or in a terminal:

    sudo snap install emote
    [image]
11. [**Emoji OnBoard keyboard layout**](https://github.com/qnub/onboard-emoji) was mentioned by [Tanius, please vote the answer below up, too](https://askubuntu.com/a/1254873/30631). It is an emoji chooser layout for the default Ubuntu onscreen keyboard "Onboard". **strong text**It works for all applications. [Instructions for how to us on the github](https://github.com/qnub/onboard-emoji#how-to-use).
    [image]
12. [**smile**](https://github.com/mijorus/smile): An emoji picker for linux, with custom tags support and localization. I'll also put some random emojis here  [[Covered by OMG!Linux]](https://www.omglinux.com/smile-emoji-picker-for-linux/).
13. [**EmojiMart**](https://github.com/vemonet/EmojiMart):  Modern emoji picker popup for desktop, based on Emoji Mart, built with Tauri and Solid JS [[Covered by OMG!Linux]](https://www.omglinux.com/emoji-mart-picker/).
14. There might be an [**answer to an earlier question that still works for you**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662777/emoji-picker-tool).

**Which emoji font will be shown?**
When there are more than one emoji fonts installed, different apps use different fonts:
e.g. Segoe Emoji (seguiemj.ttf) is used by the [Wire desktop App](https://wire.com/en/download/) by default, Emoji One (emojione-android.ttf) is used by Evolution by default on my Ubuntu 20.04 system.

**How to only use Noto Emoji font?**
Uninstall the other emoji fonts:
Search in **[Font Manager](https://fontmanager.github.io/)** (font-manager in the normal package list) for emoji fonts.
Open the corresponding folders as root.
Delete the emoji fonts (e.g. seguiemj.ttf, emojione-android.ttf).
Restart the app (or login/logout of the session).

For Thunderbird to behave, [I did this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029675/30631):
I created `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/01-emoji.conf` with the following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>serif</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Then run:

```
fc-cache -f -v
```

The answers to this question can be helpful, too: [18.04: color emoji not showing up at all in Chrome, only partially in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029661/18-04-color-emoji-not-showing-up-at-all-in-chrome-only-partially-in-firefox)
And a similar answer: [How do I configure the default emoji font to be used in OS/Browser?](https://askubuntu.com/a/963868/30631).

Comment: Is the keyboard available in other Ubuntu 18.04 flavors too ?

Comment: @SushantChaudhary Option 1, 3, 4, 5 probably work, 2 only with a GNOME desktop.

Comment: For #3 is there a way to disable searching (from Activities view) other characters that aren't emojis? usually searching for something brings me an Arab character or the old emojis (like this one ☺) not the color ones

Comment: hi, for #8 i have problem, i can show the emoji selector, but when tapping on the emoji, nothing happen, when switch to regular char, the onscreen keyboard can type as usual, though the #1 and #2 is working flawlessly, os is pop os 19.04, any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @Felipe Did you find a solution for your problems? If yes, could you please share it with us?

Comment: @Filbuntu nope, still have the problem

Comment: @am05mhz  I would file a bug report and you may get some help there. If you find a solution, please tell us here, too. Thanks!

Comment: The Ctrl-Shift-E, then space, keyboard shortcut, is annoying if you are using a keyboard that doesn't include the "e" key.

Comment: @Flimm This is indeed annoying, maybe there is a way to change this. If you find a way, please share it here, thanks!
By the way, have you found a solution for your #8-Problem mentioned in 2019?

Comment: @Filbuntu We disagree about harsh: this is what upvoting and downvoting are for. If an answer provides false information when for the specific reason I came to read it in the first sentence, that is 100% worthy of a downvote. However, the error has been corrected, so I will recind the downvote. :)

Comment: @Filbuntu Given the present exhaustiveness of your answer, would you also mention [EF*CK Chat Keyboard](https://efck-chat-keyboard.github.io)? Looks a good alternative. :)

Comment: @K3---rnc Thank you for the hint. Have you programmed this? The features look really nice. What is the symbol at the bottom right for?

Comment: @Filbuntu Might have. The site is strong with symbolism, but assuming you mean _the_ symbol, I think it's meant to serve as a lucky charm, even in face of the absurdity of some parts of the website, unmistakably of the generous kind. Good job on spotting that! Either you must be web browsing from a terminal, or your screen gamut is insane. :)

Comment: @K3---rnc Does "Might have" refer to the question "Have you programmed this"? - I use a dark theme in my Firefox and with this **_the special small symbol at the bottom right_** is clearly visible ... - As _the symbol_ at the bottom right is ambiguous, can be misunderstood and it is even deliberately made hard to spot, I am leaning towards not adding this tool to the answer. But people can read about it in your comment. Maybe the programmer of the tool can get rid of some of the symbolism and think about changing the name, too, all of it is not needed for a really nice tool.

Comment: @Filbuntu I happen to be of the opinion that the name had fallen neatly into place. You have to differentiate when you're as late to the game. :) Re ambiguity, I can assure you Unicode v1.1 Standard would not comprise a symbol that praised whatever you have in mind—yet it apparently would what I have. Thanks for the feedback and consideration, anyway. 

Comment: @Filbuntu I do understand your reservations. Definitely need to make the sign much more inconspicuous under dark theme conditions. Can't afford to scare people! 

Comment: @K3---rnc Thank you for your understanding. - Why would you use a symbol that might scare people and even hide it? What will people think when they discover it? - I think you can differentiate yourself with the excellency of the app and regular further development.

Comment: @Filbuntu You would hide it precisely not to scare people. The very few find it curious, sometimes exploringly, which is a curiosity in and of itself. :) Thanks for the warm wishes, but as one of the few contributors for the time being, _I think_ the app to be stable/feature-complete (—what would you miss?) and the artistic expression well served*. Happy to further discuss views and values, but far less so in public. I for the life of me couldn't find your email in public sources, but conversely might be possible, if you want, via https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903890/1090455?

Comment: @K3---rnc Thanks for the clarification and conversation invitation. Although I like chatting, time is currently scarce and I don't have anything to add at the moment.

Comment: Feel free to add Cross-Platform Emoji Picker to your list if you like. It was designed specifically for Ubuntu (since most Ubuntu options haven't been great) but _also_ works on Windows and Mac. https://askubuntu.com/a/1482199/48214

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for the hint. I asked some questions in a comment to your answer.

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for the answer. I am bit cautious to recommend an app that is only downloadable from a private page and that has not given access to the source code, e.g. via Gitlab. An AppImage is a black box for most people.

Comment: I must say I find it a bit annoying that this _answer_ contains several answers. Even though they seem sorted reasonably, it means you have to read through several of them if the first ones don’t work for you, and also it’s not possible to vote for one specifically.

Comment: BTW the Gnome Shell extension Emoji Selector is not compatible with the latest version of Gnome. There is a fork that supports it: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6242/emoji-copy/

Comment: @DidierL Thank you for your comments. You have point there regarding the answer with several answers. I am not sure, though, whether it is acceptable to split the answer in many now. - Thank you for the tip regarding Emoji Copy, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 47):

Use the following keyboard shortcuts:

1. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>, then press <kbd>Space</kbd>.
2. You should see the *Emoji Choice* popup where you can select your unicode character.

   <sup>Note: To cancel the selection, press <kbd>Escape</kbd> few times.</sup>

[image: Emoji Choice on GNOME Terminal, Animals & Nature, Unicode special characters]

Tested on Ubuntu Cosmic (18.10). It should work in editors, terminal, web browsers and other applications.

Comment: This even works in Firefox and LibreOffice Writer (in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and ctrl + shift + e, then spaces does nothing, how to enable that?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 and ctrl + shift + e, then spaces does nothing, how to enable that?

Comment: Go to Settings / Region and Language / Manage Installed Languages / Keyboard Input System Method. Choose XIM. Restart. May break chats with your waifu.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84464#issuecomment-559415030

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: Installing Emote and it works for me ! https://snapcraft.io/emote

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is shipped with ubuntu. Make sure that ibus-daemon is running if it doesn’t work. The shortcut can be configured with `ibus-setup`.

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 20.04, no need to install any extra package. Thanks.

Comment: -1 `<CTRL>+<SHIFT>+<E>`, followed by `<SPACE>` does not give access to an emoji picker on Gnome with XOrg in 20.04.

Comment: It works for me, but with pop-up layout is hidden if input is near the bottom of screen. (exp Messenger input)

Comment: This didn't work for me in Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: In Ubuntu 23.10 default shortcut is `Super`+`.` or alternative `Super`+`;`

You can change the shortcut with `ibus-setup` command.

Comment: For me it is `Ctrl` + `.`. BUT you should not press `space` right away, what you type there is the search keyword. So 1️⃣ `Ctrl`+`.`... 2️⃣ insert search keyword ... 3️⃣ press `space`, you'll get the closest match ... 4️⃣ Press `Enter` if  or `space` again to list all matches

Answer (score 20):

Emote is a modern, system-wide emoji picker which is a decent option in 2021.

https://github.com/tom-james-watson/emote

It should work on all major desktop environments and supports both X11 and Wayland.

[image: emote app window]

#### Installation:

[image: Get it from the Snap Store]

```
sudo snap install emote
```

Comment: Tamale test: 

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Emoji OnBoard](https://github.com/qnub/onboard-emoji) keyboard layout. It is an emoji chooser layout for the default Ubuntu onscreen keyboard "Onboard":

[image]

Unlike many other solutions, it works together with all applications. While for example [emoji-keyboard](https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/emoji-keyboard) can only insert the emoji characters directly into Gtk applications and otherwise is restricted to copying them into the clipboard. So there is definitely a way to do software keyboards right under Linux, and I wonder why it's not more widespread ...

Answer (score 1):

[Mojibar](https://github.com/muan/mojibar) is also a great alternative that is X-platform and not dependent of the desktop environment ! :)

The maintainer is not merging any PR for sometime but I guess that you can fork it and use your own version of the repo. :D

Comment: @Flimm updated, it's archived by the maintainer tho.

Answer (score 0):

I will just add additional information to @Filbuntu 's answer on how to add GNOME Shell Extensions Emoji Selector to Ubuntu Firefox based on my experience.

First you will need to open add ons menu, and add this extension:
GNOME Shell integration
[Gnome Shell Integration Screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN5OM.png)

After that, you can go to this page https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1162/emoji-selector/

If there is an error message like "native host connector is not detected", then you need to install chrome-gnome-shell using the following step based on [this answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107849/1557897)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

After chrome-gnome-shell, you can refresh the gnome shell extensions website, then the message should be disappear, and can turning on the switch which is located at the top right corner. After that, then the emoji icon should appear on your top bar and you can start using it by clicking on it and choose the icon you want.

[switch on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2YVI.png)

[emoji icon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifugc.png)

Answer (score 0):

GTK based apps (most apps in Ubuntu, including Firefox but not Chrome) have available an emoji picker:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>, and a  `̲e̲` will appear.
2. Type your emoji search keyword.
3. Press <kbd>space</kbd> to preview the closest match.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept, or <kbd>space</kbd> again to see other matches (a popup should appear as the image below ).

[image]