# What does [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [e] do, while typing text?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I already knew that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> would allow to type a character by giving its Unicode hexadecimal representation: an underlined u appears, you type the code and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>; <kbd>e</kbd>; <kbd>9</kbd>; <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives the character é.

Now I've just noticed that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> lets an underline e appear, in a very similar manner, but I can't figure out what it does.

Does someone know? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am using the French keyboard layout from Switzerland, but sometimes also the Swedish one from Sweden. I don't think it is relevant though.

Comment: Two years later: Did Ubuntu just remove that feature?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> is the emoji entry shortcut/hotkey sequence.

It produces an underlined "e̲", if you type "joy" after it (so it looks like "e̲j̲o̲y̲") the whole word will be underlined. On pressing a whitespace entry key, like spacebar, you should then get the "e̲j̲o̲y̲" text changed to "" (the emoji character selected by your current application).

Comment: I think you can adapt this to a separate answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045915/how-to-insert-an-emoji-into-a-text-in-ubuntu-18-04) too.

Comment: I can't find a list of codes anywhere, happened on the "joy" one. Apparently the emojis are based on [EmojiOne](https://www.emojione.com/emoji/1f602) and I thought based on that linked page that the shortcode without the separators would be the entry code, but only "joy", "kiss" and "like" works for me. "grinning", "smile", "frown", "sad", "couplekiss" etc. as modifiers after the shortcut don't work, they give no entry. Links from [bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/+bug/1738500) show you can disable it with ibus-setup, but I don't have ibus installed on my Kubuntu.

Comment: I think simple simple emoticons (e.g. **`:) :( :p :D`** etc.) may work, please try them. I don't have a 18.04 installation with me right now.

Comment: They don't work for me, and I saw a comment elsewhere that they didn't work. You can get the emoticons via the unicode ctrl+shift+u entry though, which gives the EmojiOne images in my short test. 

Comment: This code commit gives a list of the emoji key sequences, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/commit/66a7da8eb9cecc6fcc646a5f7a32ae9823738584.

Comment: Thank you! Now can we disable it?  It conflicts with IDEA/Android Studio's shortcut for Recently Changed Files.

Comment: I've seen other answers on disabling, maybe on unix SE site? Ask again if you can't find it. On mobile at present.

Comment: @Peter You can disable it by launching IBus Preferences -> Emoji tab -> Emoji Annotation -> ... -> Delete key
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/528509-How-to-disable-CTRL-SHIFT-e-gnome-emoji-shortcut#:~:text=Re%3A%20How%20to%20disable%20CTRL%2DSHIFT%2De%20gnome%20emoji%20shortcut,-Stumbled%20upon%20this&text=Then%20hit%20the%20%22Emoji%22%20tab,if%20you%20really%20want%20to.

Answer (score 75):

Just issue the command bellow:

```
ibus-setup
```

And change it on the Emoji tab as the picture bellow

[image: IBus Preferences Window]

Comment: I've modified the emoji annotation shortcut as suggested here, and it seems to work in e.g. gedit and LibreOffice Writer, but for some reason the emoji annotation is still activated by Ctrl+Shift+e in Visual Studio Code. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @LiamBaker I have the same issue, have you found any solution?

Comment: From my research, it seemed to be because I'm using the snap version of VSCode, which may include an old version of GTK which still has this behaviour (the 'feature' was removed in GTK 3.24, I believe). Apparently it is fixed if one installs the apt/deb version instead, although I haven't tried this yet; let me know if that works for you!

Comment: @LiamBaker Since `ctrl+shift+e` usecase in vscode is to open explorer, my solution was to change the combo to `ctrl+e`. (or alternative is `ctrl+p`):


```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "workbench.view.explorer"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+e",
    "command": "-workbench.view.explorer"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+e",
    "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePreviousInFilePicker",
    "when": "inFilesPicker && inQuickOpen"
  }

```

Comment: For VS Code this works in Ubuntu terminal: `$ GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" code`. You can also add an alias for it in your .bashrc file: `alias code='GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" code'`

Comment: If you installed VS Code using Snap, here how to disable the combination: https://askubuntu.com/a/1269239/229740

Comment: I just updated to Ubuntu 21.10 and found that the emoji annotation was appearing every time I pressed "ctrl+." (ctrl-period). I couldn't figure out why or how to change it until I found this Q&A. It was driving me batty because I use that key combination very, very frequently in VSCode and IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: From GUI (`ibus-setup`) or [from CLI](https://askubuntu.com/a/1428373/349837)

Answer (score 3):

Based on other answers here, I discovered that this keyboard shortcut defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> for anyone running Ubuntu with the KDE desktop environment.

Typing this shortcut displays the same "underlined e" character in a text box and doesn't seem to want to disappear unless I type some additional characters after it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then it just leaves me with the additional characters I typed.

[image: the "underlined e" character displayed after pressing this shortcut]

using the `ibus-setup` command, I was able to confirm that, on my system, this emoji entry shortcut was set to `<Control>period` which I found myself accidentally hitting occasionally. Changing it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> will likely make this a lot less likely for me to accidentally activate