# Keyboard application Shortcut

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys

It used to be the case that using <kbd>Ctrl + ;</kbd> (semi-colon) (specifically but not limited to) Google Sheets would insert the current date in a cell (assuming the cell format is set to do so) but just recently, I have noted that this shortcut produces an underlined e char and pressing space adds an additional context menu.
Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> removes the character and control to the cell is restored after another keypress or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

This is not specific to Google Sheets and is thus posted here. It also occurs in terminal with the same behaviour and in other apps across the spectrum.

Nor is it specific to my PC in isolation. I tried this on my 20.04 instance and it performed correctly. I also tried it on another 22.04 instance (with the same keyboard layout but a different keyboard) and experienced the same issue so it appears to be a feature of 22.04.2 with Gnome 42.5 and 5.19.0-41-generic Kernel on both 22.04 instances.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue. It's not super serious as manually inputting the date in Sheets and using the semi-colon on its own elsewhere works fine but it seems something has changed along the way.

Comment: Changed does not mean broken.

Comment: @graham in *many* cases unfortunately, if a default behavior *changes* that's not "broken".  It sounds however like you *might* have some kind of a bug that you've discovered.  You should consider filing a bug against the kernel and then report it *as* a bug.  Unfortunately the only advice *we* might give you is "try using an older kernel" because we can't *fix* kernel bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not actually a bug nor something "broken" - it's simply a default change in GNOME.

Previously, GNOME had a default keyboard shortcut for Emoji Mode of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> for this (see [What does [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [e] do, while typing text?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083913/what-does-ctrl-shift-e-do-while-typing-text) which shows this in an older version of Ubuntu).

However, it seems they changed the default to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> recently.  This is confirmed in my 22.04 machine when we look at `ibus-setup` (note I run my system theme in Dark Mode, which is why everything is dark on my screen):

[image]

You can simply change this with `ibus-setup` (execute this on the command line and it opens up the iBus Preferences window) and change the keyboard shortcut.  Nothing's *broken* but a change was made.  This is likely in the GNOME upstream changelogs somewhere, or was a change decided upon by Ubuntu.

In either case, this is readily fixable and not a bug nor "broken".  Changed defaults are not a "breakage" in anything.

Comment: your valuable time in pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated Thomas, thank you. Bad choice of words on my part - I was indeed flagging a potentially changed default and seeking a solution to restore it to the original condition which I have now done.