# Ubuntu feature for writing emojis without any external application

Tags: keyboard, gui, emoji

I know Ubuntu can show emojis, but I've seen Windows 10 has this extra feature: you press super + . and then a window appears with emojis (and other regular characters that can't be found on the keyboard, like the character map!), so you can select any to type it in the text you're writing in any application. I think this is cool, because it's a little tiresome to depend on, for example, a Firefox extension to write them in the web when I'm using the computer.

So, these are my doubts:

1. Just to be sure: does Ubuntu lacks this feature? If not, how can I write directly emojis without external applications?
2. (If last answer was "no") Is this feature already considered for future Ubuntu versions?
3. (Again, if last was "no") Is there any channel, any via where I can include this suggestion to the Ubuntu developer team?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 at this moment (default desktop enviroment, GNOME), but anyway I think this would be nice for any *actual* DE if it's not implemented yet.

Cheers!

Comment: Does [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en) help? BTW, I guess you're using gnome, but since there are many Desktop Environments available for Ubuntu it would be best to include it in the question.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how can I use emojis with it if that's possible (I've Tweaks installed and I can write, for example, ¾ with this function). Didn't think about the desktop environment, I didn't realize that it depends on it. I'll add it, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an emoji into a text in Ubuntu 18.04 and later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045915/how-to-insert-an-emoji-into-a-text-in-ubuntu-18-04-and-later)