# How to add Emojis on Ubuntu

Tags: emoji

**Hi, I am newbie user on Ubuntu**

Want to ask, how do you use emojis in Ubuntu?
Does Ubuntu have a shortcut key too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an emoji into a text in Ubuntu 18.04 and later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045915/how-to-insert-an-emoji-into-a-text-in-ubuntu-18-04-and-later)

Comment: Some of the solutions in the linked dup don't work on 20.04

Comment: Then they should be edited to note that.

Comment: @muru They have been which is how I know. I mention it because the close vote as a dup may not be valid for the OP.

Comment: @24601 why would that make it any less valid? If anything any new methods, should be posted on the dupe target, which is what we generally do here - collect answers for the same core problem in one question. After all, the problem itself doesn't change across versions.